# Jquery validate input to eight integers and two decimals

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I've tried this code but I guess that I have an error with my regex since it's always `true`.

Besides the regex, I also have a problem with `keypress` since I'm testing the value before adding the new char, I don't want to use `keyup` since I don't know where the last char was added (the user will not always input the char at the end of the input field).

I would appreciate a good solution, thanks.

```
$('.myInputField').keypress(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var regexTest = /^[0-9]{0,8}[.][0-9]{0,2}|[0-9]{0,8}$/;
    var ok = regexTest.test(val);
    if(ok)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want a regex like this:

```
/^\d{0,8}(\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

You were using `.` instead of `\.`, but `.` would match *any* character.

The `?` near the end allows you to have ".12" or not have it.

`\d` is a short-cut way of restricting to digits.

Please consider not using `keypress` for this - `keyup` (better) or `change` (best) would be other options to think about.

If you need "extremely responsive" feedback (can't just use `change`), consider doing something like this (Please use a better approach than the simple CSS I've used in the example):

```
$('.myInputField').keyup(function(e){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var regexTest = /^\d{0,8}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
  var ok = regexTest.test(val);
  if(ok) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
  } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  }
});
```

[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GgmJp/)

Note: I've also changed the code so that if you enter a `.` in the input, we expect you to put *at least one digit* following the decimal.  If you really don't want this edit, change the `\d{1,2}` to `\d{0,2}`

Comment: and do you have any idea how to overcome the keypress problem?

Comment: instead of kepress() you could use change() this will run whenever the value of the textbox has been changed

Comment: thanks but i don't want to allow the user to focus out from the input field if the input is not valid, so i cannot use change.